# How do I plug this SATA power cable into a PSU with only 4 pins?

Tags: hard-drive, power-supply, sata, power

I got a new PSU and I can't run my hard drives off of the power supply because this is the cable.

[image: cable]

And this is my power supply:

[image: power supply]

My old power supply allowed me to plug the cable for my hard drives in, but this one won't. Do I need a different cable of some sort? I've been Googling for days and can't seem to find anything.

Comment: The PSU didn't come with a bunch of different cables to plug in?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I actually brought it over to Australia from America, and I think the cables got lost in the process. I'm trying to find out where to get cables from that can replace them.

Comment: that looks suspiciously like a cable for another modular PSU... in fact it looks a lot like a seasonic cable. Those thing arn't standard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a modular power supply, meaning the power cables are detachable.  Detachable cables are great, as you only use the cables you need and dont have the clutter of the cables you dont.  Without the clutter of cables, there is better airflow (in theory).

I am guessing you got this PSU second hand, correct?  Hopefully, whoever gave you the PSU has the cables lying around.  If not, you can always order the cables from the PSU manufacturer, or from the a [web store](https://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Description=modular%20power%20supply%20cables&Submit=ENE).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you have is known as a [modular power supply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_supply_unit_(computer)#Modular_power_supplies) unit. As Wikipedia explains:

> A modular power supply provides a detachable cable system, offering the ability to remove unused connections at the expense of a small amount of extra electrical resistance introduced by the additional connector.[24] This reduces clutter, removes the risk of dangling cables interfering with other components, and can improve case airflow. Many modular supplies have some permanent multi-wire cables with connectors at the ends, such as PC main and four-pin Molex, though newer supplies marketed as "Fully Modular" allow even these to be disconnected.

As stated, the main benefit of a modular power supply is basically simplifying cable management. With a regular power supply, you basically have a pile of cables spilling out of the PSU and that can be messy—and even risky in some cases—to manage.

In contrast, a modular power supply uses somewhat generic connectors—like the ones you can see on your unit pictured—to connect necessary cables to it.

So if you need to connect that 5-pin cable to your PSU you need to purchase an appropriate modular PSU cable to do that. Luckily these units are quite common and cables can be found in most PC part shops. Just [Google for “Modular Power Supply”](https://www.google.com/search?ei=sguJWsDaG4Kd5gKswJTQAg&q=Modular%20Power%20Supply&oq=Modular%20Power%20Supply&gs_l=psy-ab.12...0.0.0.3209.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.Y7yQ3AzRh0c) and find them that way.

Comment: **Be extremely careful with the last bit of advice.** Modular power supply cable connectors and pinouts are not standardized. Using a cable which was not provided with your modular power supply is risky -- even if it plugs in, it may supply inappropriate voltages to connected devices.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is known as a "modular" PSU, rather than hardwiring the cables to the PSU the manufacturer uses connectors. This reduces clutter from unused cables inside the PC case. Some PSUs are "partially modular" with critical cables hardwired and optional cables on connectors and others are "fully modular" with all cables detachable.

Unfortunately there is no standardisation of the type or pinout of the connectors on the PSU end of the cables. Different PSUs may use different connector types or worse use the same connector type but with different pin-outs. Using the wrong cables can easilly destroy computer hardware.

When sourcing cables for a modular PSU you therefore need to be extremely careful to buy cables that are compatible with your PSU.